# How to pass data from python to php?

Tags: python

I have tried this code(**Python side**)...

```
import requests
import json

keys = {"name": "John"}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}

r = requests.post("http://localhost/Python_/test.php", data = keys, headers = headers)

print r.url
print r.status_code
```

On php side, I am trying to get the name..

```
print_r($_POST['keys']);
```

And I am getting this error..
**Notice**:  Undefined index: keys in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Python_\test.php** on line **8**

I tried it on REST client, the code shows the name on REST client but on localhost it got this error.

Comment: Do you have a web server set up that's listening for requests to the PHP script (at localhost)?

Comment: Try `print_r($_POST)`. It will show `array( [name] => John)`. On second thought, it will not. You are using the HTTP `PUT` method. Try `file_get_contents('php://input');`.

Comment: It is post() .. my apology

Comment: @Jack Yes I do have localhost up & running. However it shows that undefined index while running at localhost. When I use REST Client, it works fine with it.

Comment: As Boldewyn said above, try doing a `print_r($_POST);` in your PHP.

Comment: @Jack ,Boldewyn Thanks guys!
The mistake I had made was ..I had to get $_POST['name'] & not $_POST['keys']

Comment: You're welcome! (By the way, you can also `echo file_get_contents('php://input');` with POST requests to see, what exactly the client sent with the request.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your post data will be the `keys` dictionary.
Your php code should be `print_r($_POST['name']);`